# Populate Material dropdow menu from Rest call data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to populate dropdown menu with data from Rest API. I tried this:

```
<Select id="country-helper">
{array.map((element) => (
     <MenuItem value={element.code}>{element.country}</MenuItem>
       ))}
</Select>
```

I created this service with Axios:

export interface CountriesDTO {
country?: string;
code: string;
}

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { CountriesDTO } from "./types";

const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api";

export async function getCountries(): Promise<AxiosResponse<CountriesDTO[]>> {
  return await axios.get<CountriesDTO[]>(
    `${baseUrl}/merchants/onboarding/countries`
  );
}
```

It's not clear how I can make the call into the React page. I tried this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            getCountries()
                .then((resp) => {
                    console.log(resp.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        };

    }, []);
```

How I can populate the dropdown using the data from GET API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your function `getData` from useEffect, you should also create state array to store your data.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState<CountriesDTO[]>([]); // <=== create state array

useEffect(() => {
  getData(); // <=== call your function
}, []);

const getData = async () => {
  getCountries()
    .then((resp) => {
      setArray(resp.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: okj, but how I can use the `getData()` payload to populate the dropdown items?

Comment: Your getaData will fetch your array from the backend then it will store the result into the state array. So you will use the state array to populate your menu items. I declared the state array check the answer.

Comment: It's better to post the whole component in case you faced a problem.

Comment: For this `line: setArray(resp.data)` I get `TS2345: Argument of type 'CountriesDTO[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.   Type 'CountriesDTO[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.     Type 'CountriesDTO' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: Just to mention. This is the payload: https://pastebin.com/p719Kqke

Comment: I updated the answer, useState has a generic type. We can use the type CountriesDTO[] as a parameter for useState.

Comment: One additional question. How I can define a new array constant? I think that the keyword `array` is reserved?

Comment: Just rename your state like this const [array, setArray] = useState<CountriesDTO[]>([]); ====> const [countries, setCountries] = useState<CountriesDTO[]>([]);

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Comment: Just to verify, do you need to change the name [array, setArray]?

Comment: I want to populate a second drop down with different API call and different data. How I can do it?

Comment: This example can help you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-guubq7